# Prove the sequent is valid for the formulas

Tags: logic

> Prove that if $\Gamma$ is a sequence of formulas, and the sequent $\Gamma, \phi \vdash \psi$ is valid then the sequent $\Gamma, \neg \psi \vdash \neg \phi$ is also valid. Do not use soundness/completeness.

I would like some assistance here. Without soundness, completeness how can I proceed further?

I see no way to proceed. Hints/ideas/theories appreciated!

Comment: You will need to use the basic definition of what it means for a sequence $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ to be valid. What is that definition?

Comment: @Bram28, derives. But I am not sure how to give it a "meaning?"

Comment: You call it a sequent, which suggest that it is a logical object, rather than a claim about logical objects (some systems do this). So, I was hoping that maybe this 'sequent' was defined by your text/professor.  But if it simply means 'derives', then we will ned to know the particular inference rules for the system, because without being able to assume completeness, we cannot give a meta-logical proof ... we would have to provide an actual derivation .. or at least provide the relevant parts.  Are you using a book?

Comment: @Bram28, I would guess natural deduction, since thats what we learned

Comment: OK, that helps ... it tells me you are probably not using sequence as objects. Still, there are many different natural deduction systems, each with their own set of rules, and again, without being able to assume completeness, we need to know those rules to answer this question. So ... is it possible to post those rules?  (probably all I need is however the 'proof by contradiction' or 'Reductio ad Absurdum'  is formalized ... do you have a $\neg \ Intro$ maybe?

Answer (score 1):

A *sequent* $\Gamma' \vdash \Delta$ is satisfied by an interprettaion $\mathcal I$ if either some formula in $\Gamma'$ is not satisfied by $\mathcal I$ or some formula in $\Delta$ is satisfied by $\mathcal I$.

A sequent is *valid* if it is satisfied by every interpretation.

Thus, we have to apply the above definition to the case when $\Gamma' = \Gamma \cup \{ \phi \}$ and $\Delta = \{ \psi \}$.

We assume that $Γ, \phi ⊢ \psi$ is *valid* and we can disregard the "context" $\Gamma$; for an interpretation $\mathcal I$ whatever, we have two cases to consider; either:

*(i)* $\phi$ is not satisfied by $\mathcal I$.

In this case, we have that $\lnot \phi$ is satisfied and thus the sequent: $Γ, \lnot \psi ⊢ \lnot \phi$ is satisfied by $\mathcal I$.

Or:

*(ii)* $\psi$ is satisfied by $\mathcal I$.

In this case, we have that $\lnot \psi$ is not satisfied and thus the sequent: $Γ, \lnot \psi ⊢ \lnot \phi$ is again satisfied by $\mathcal I$.

Answer (score 1):

In natural deduction: See that $ \Gamma, \neg \psi, \phi \vdash \neg \psi$ (Reflexivity) and $ \Gamma, \neg \psi, \phi \vdash \psi$ (Monotonicity using the hypothesis), thus $ \Gamma, \neg \psi, \phi \vdash \bot$, using introduction of the implication, follows that $\Gamma, \neg \psi \vdash  \phi \to \bot$, but $\phi \to \bot = \neg \phi.$ To be clearer, you need especificate your rules.